# How to keep fragment state after replace transaction?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-mapview

I have two fragments(suppose **FragmentA** and **FragmentB**) in an Android app that I switch between using a **BottomBar**.

I have a list of data that is being fetched using **Retrofit** that I am displaying using a **RecyclerView** in **FragmentA** and I have a **MapView** in **FragmentB**.

My problem is whenever I switch back from *FragmentB* to *FragmentA*, **the API calls fetches the list of data again**. And when I switch from *FragmentA* to *FragmentB* **the MapView is rendered again from start.**

**Is there a way that I can keep the state of FragmentA i.e. the list of data as it is until I destroy the Activity? and to keep the MapView in FragmentB as it is?**

I used the following to replace a fragment.

```
public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment // This can be FragmentA or FragmentB) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.framelayout, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

> I just want to fragments to keep their state and not re-initialize
>   every thing until the activity is destroyed. I guess that the life
>   cycle methods of fragments play an important role here.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: use viewpager instead of replace fragment every time

Answer (score 2):

[Architecture components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/) are better suited to your scenario. Use [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) and [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel).

1. Inside the Activity, Create a view model and update the live data with the server response.
2. In the Fragment, Use the Live data to update the views.

In this case, ViewModel lifecycle is attached to the activity and the fragment transactions won't affect the data stored. Since you're updating the data from the LiveData there will only be one api call made when the activity is created. In addition to that, ViewModel survives the orientation changes, which means your LiveData still holds the API response.

Comment: That is a great solution and I am willing to try this on some other project. I am working on a project from few years ago and refactoring that to use Architecture Components will take a lot of time and I can't do that currently due to tight deadlines. Can you please suggest some other way that could be an alternative for this simple purpose?

Answer (score 1):

In MyActivity,
**Declare both fragments objects above onCreate:**

```
private Fragment1 fragment1 = new Fragment1();
private Fragment2 fragment1 = new Fragment2();
```

Clicking on BottomBar, you can set click for both fragments to show and hide.

**Set fragment1 selected**

```
private void fragment1Selected() {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if (fragment1 == null || !fragment1.isAdded()) {
            fragment1 = new Fragment1();
            transaction.add(R.id.framelayout, fragment1);
        } else {
            transaction.show(fragment1);
        }

        if (fragment2 != null)
            transaction.hide(fragment2);

        transaction.commit();
    }
```

**Set fragment2 selected**

```
private void fragment2Selected() {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if (fragment2 == null || !fragment2.isAdded()) {
            fragment2 = new Fragment2();
            transaction.add(R.id.framelayout, fragment2);
        } else {
            transaction.show(fragment2);
        }

        if (fragment1 != null)
            transaction.hide(fragment1);

        transaction.commit();
    }
```

Comment: Not at all a reusable solution. What if I had five fragments? Would I just write five methods for them? Silly.

Comment: Of course not reusable solution. but answer is to get solution of your problem any how. There are many other ways you can try.

Answer (score 0):

To build upon Rumit Patel's answer

I created a function to display the first fragment

```
private fun initialFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
    val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayoutMA,fragment)
    fragmentTransaction.commit()
}
```

Then for every subsequent fragment, I passed the previous fragment (the fragment I want to hide) alongside the new one (the one I want to show) to this function

```
private fun fragmentSelected(oldFragment: Fragment, newFragment: Fragment) {
    val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()

    fragmentTransaction.hide(oldFragment)

    if (!newFragment.isAdded) {
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frameLayoutMA, newFragment)
    }

    else {
        fragmentTransaction.show(newFragment)
    }

    fragmentTransaction.commit()
}
```

If you want to hide multiple fragments then you could create an arrayList and add all the fragments except the one you want to show

```
fun fragmentArrayList(exception: Int): ArrayList<Fragment> {

    val fragmentList: ArrayList<Fragment> = ArrayList()

    if (exception != fragment1) {
        fragmentList.add(fragment1)
    }

    if (exception != fragment2 {
        fragmentList.add(fragment2)
    }

    if (exception != fragment3 {
        fragmentList.add(fragment3)
    }

    if (exception != fragment4 {
        fragmentList.add(fragment4)
    }

    return fragmentList
}
```

and hide all fragments except the new one with this variant of the second function

```
    private fun fragmentSelected(oldFragments: ArrayList<Fragment>, newFragment: Fragment) {
    val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()

    for (oldFragment in oldFragments) {
        fragmentTransaction.hide(oldFragment)
    }

    if (!newFragment.isAdded) {
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frameLayoutMA, newFragment)
    }

    else {
        fragmentTransaction.show(newFragment)
    }

    fragmentTransaction.commit()
}
```